# Finding the State Space Model of a linearized Equation of satellite

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

I have been trying for days to find how to convert the linearized Equation of a satellite given by the equation attached in the image to STATE SPACE equation.

Please I have been struggling for days. I am a newbie in control system.

Please do help out.

$$
\ddot\varepsilon+D\,\dot\varepsilon+K\,\varepsilon=B\,u \tag{1}
$$

Where 
$$
\varepsilon=
\begin{pmatrix}
r \\ \theta-\omega\,t
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\text{radial-deviation-from-R} \\ \text{angular-position}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
u=
\begin{pmatrix}
u_1 \\ u_2
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
\text{radial-thrust} \\ 
\text{tangential-thrust}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
D=
\begin{pmatrix}
2\omega\over\ R & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
K=
\begin{pmatrix}
-2\omega^2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
B=
\begin{pmatrix}
1\over m & 0 \\ 0 & 1\over m \end{pmatrix}
$$

Want to convert above equation $(1)$ to state space equation of the form 
$$
\dot x = A\,x+B\,u
$$

Also if $y=\dot\theta$ is observed at the output what will be the transfer function?

[Satellite Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmGOv.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: I have done that now. Thanks for the advise. Please really need answer to this question.

Comment: Someone should please help on this. An idea or something to work with so that I can continue from there. I learnt question get answered very fast on this forum. Thanks in anticipation for your responses.

Comment: Thanks Kwin. Not really duplicate actually. But I am going through it now. Will still love if someone can give me a better hint.

Comment: Where you able to rewrite your second order differential equation to a system of first order differential equations?

Comment: This question is not duplicate as some as tagged it here. This is a MIMO system unlike the various SISO systems I was directed to. I have figured it out anyway on my own. But I will have to say the forum has not been of much help.

Comment: Yes down that now